# In Compose KeyboardOptions imeAction does not change from Next toDone when switching textfields

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a view that has multiple textfields as shown in the code below. I want to change the `KeyboardOptions` imeAction from `ImeAction.Next` to `ImeAction.Done` in the last textfield but whenever I get to the last textfield, the keyboard still shows Next unless I touch the screen.
The same behavior happens when I select the last textfield, the keyboard shows the done button, but when I click on another text field that should have the Next button in the keyboard, the keyboard still shows Done unless I interact with the keyboard.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun CreateAccountView(
    viewModel: RegistrationVM? = null,
    onClose: () -> Unit,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {}
) {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember {BringIntoViewRequester()}

    var emailAddress by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var username by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    var password by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var passwordVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }//T


    var fname by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var lname by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text("") },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(onClick = onClose) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(it)) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp)
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 18.dp),
                    text = "Create your account",
                    style = TextStyle(
                        fontSize = 32.sp,
                        color = Color(0xFF7856FF)
                    )
                )
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 24.dp)
                        .onFocusEvent { event ->
                            if (event.isFocused) {

                            }
                        },
                    label = { Text("Email address") },
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                    ),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    value = emailAddress,
                    onValueChange = { newText ->
                        emailAddress = newText
                    },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            //TODO ...
                        }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                        }
                    })
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 24.dp),
                    label = { Text("Password must be 8+ characters", style = TextStyle()) },
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                    ),
                    visualTransformation = if (passwordVisible) VisualTransformation.None else PasswordVisualTransformation(),
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password,
                        autoCorrect = false,
                        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.None
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    maxLines = 1,
                    value = password,
                    onValueChange = { newText ->
                        password = newText
                    },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        Row(
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                        ) {
                            TextButton(onClick = {
                                passwordVisible = !passwordVisible
                            }) {
                                Text("Show")
                            }
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                //TODO ...
                            }) {
                                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 24.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically

                ) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(.5f),
                        label = { Text("First name") },
                        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                            unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                        ),
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                            autoCorrect = false,
                        ),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Next) }
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        value = fname,
                        onValueChange = { newText ->
                            fname = newText
                        },
                        trailingIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                //TODO ...
                            }) {
                                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                            }
                        })
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(.5f),                        ,
                        label = { Text("Last name") },
                        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                            unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                        ),
                        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                            imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
                        ),
                        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                            onNext = {
                                focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                            }
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        value = lname,
                        onValueChange = { newText ->
                            lname = newText
                        },
                        trailingIcon = {
                            IconButton(onClick = {
                                //TODO ...
                            }) {
                                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
                Text(
                    text = "This will be your unique identification",
                    style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Light),
                    color = Color.Gray
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 8.dp)
                        .onFocusEvent { event ->
                            if (event.isFocused) {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    delay(200) // needed to show the button at the bottom
                                    bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    ,
                    label = { Text("Username") },
                    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                        unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Gray,
                        unfocusedLabelColor = Color.Gray,
                    ),
/// ******* ******* ******* ****** I am using Done, it should be done when I get here but is not when I transition from the previous textfield to this one. :(.  *************,

                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
                    ),
                    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                        onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }
                    ),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    value = username,
                    onValueChange = { newText ->
                        username = newText
                    },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                             //TODO
                        }) {
                            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Close, contentDescription = "Menu")
                        }
                    }
                ) // End of Username
                
                PrimaryButton(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    enabled = false,
                ) {
                    Text("Finish filling out the field above")
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp))
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution, not sure if I it's just me. I am using BOM version 2023.08.00

Comment: Just curious, but when you've moved into the last field, I'm assuming you recomposed?

Comment: Great question, after reading your comment, I forced recomposition to see if that was the issue, but even after forcing recomposition, the keyboard still does't change. 

According to Chat GPT: 
'The reason for this behavior is that the keyboard updates the action label when it gains focus or when you interact with it. In your case, when you move to the second text field with the "Done" action, the keyboard may not immediately update to display "Done" until you interact with it (e.g., tapping the text field or pressing another key)'

Comment: Update - Oct 1 2023-  I did some testing with other devices, I saw that with Pixel phones the keyboard does change with the above code but it doesn't in Samsung devices. Still haven't find a solution to this.